# Getting array element which has minimum value on a specific field on the element

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to remove an element from an array inside a collection. To remove the element, I have to look at the index (or date) field, and remove the one which has the lowest value. An example representation of my collection named "pages":

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "52e12df7e4b06e4ed65a554c"
    },
    "posts": [
        {
            "postId": {
                "$oid": "52e12e5933a9fbec1100002d"
            },
            "date": 1390489177.267876,
            "index": 1
        },
        {
            "postId": {
                "$oid": "52e12e5f33a9fb141800002c"
            },
            "date": 1390489183.277084,
            "index": 2
        }
    ],
    "skillname": "Bilardo",
    "skilltag": "Bilardo",
    "currentIndex": 2
}
```

I need to remove this element from the posts array:

```
        {
            "postId": {
                "$oid": "52e12e5933a9fbec1100002d"
            },
            "date": 1390489177.267876,
            "index": 1
        }
```

Whatever I would do, I could not manage to find the minimum "index" field in the array. The last php code I achieved to write is below:

```
$this->db->pages->find(array( 'skilltag' => 'Bilardo'), array('posts.index' => 1))->sort( array("posts.index" => -1));
```

I'm not willing to use "index" fields and also "currentIndex" field. But I put them anyways in case of not being able to work on "date" field which has timestamp values.

The above code returns an array with only one element which is an array that holds 2 elements:

```
        {
            "postId": {
                "$oid": "52e12e5933a9fbec1100002d"
            },
            "date": 1390489177.267876,
            "index": 1
        },
        {
            "postId": {
                "$oid": "52e12e5f33a9fb141800002c"
            },
            "date": 1390489183.277084,
            "index": 2
        }
```

Isn't there an aggregation function which does filtering on inside the array? I could not find any aggregation that returns the minimum value. I only found aggregation to return values between min and max values which must be given by the user -- which does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Are the embedded objects in your `posts` array field always ordered by their `date` and `index`, ascending? Based on your schema, I would assume that new posts are added to the document via the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) update operator.

If the element to remove is always at the front of the array, you could very easily use [$pop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) to remove it.